# Connecting datapoints seperated by empty points in a win form chart

Tags: winforms, mschart

I have two series to be plotted as a line chart with Win Form Charts. The first series has x,y values of

```
{(datetime1:4),(datetime2:4),(datetime3:4),(datetime4:1),(datetime5:3)}
```

And the second series has x,y values of

```
{(datetime1:4),(datetime3:14),(datetime5:6)}
```

Since the second series has `datetime2` and `datetime4` missing, I have added `DbNull.Value` as value for these points. So now the second series will be

```
{(datetime1:4),(datetime2:DbNull.Value),(datetime3:14),(datetime4:DbNull.Value),(datetime5:6)}
```

Because of this the second series shows only dots. Could you please suggest me how can I connect these empty points with the average of the two closest data points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to acheive this is

```
mySeries.EmptyPointStyle.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash; // select the style you want
mySeries.EmptyPointStyle.Color = Color.Gray; // setting the color might be required
mySeries["EmptyPointValue"] = "Average";
```

Comment: I changed mySeries to the name of the Series, and used the code as is. Since it didn't work, I replaced "EmptyPointValue" with the name of the series. But the series is still disconnected.

Comment: Can you try using `NaN` instead of `DbNull.Value`?

Comment: I replaced it with double.NaN, but still the series is disconnected.  This is how my code is foreach(SortedDictionary<string, double> map in newList)
{lineSeries = chart1.Series.Add("new Series"+i);
lineSeries.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Line;                        //additional code here .......
lineSeries.EmptyPointStyle.BorderDashStyle = ChartDashStyle.Dash; lineSeries["EmptyPointValue"] = "Average";foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> entry in map){            lineSeries.Points.AddXY(entry.Key, entry.Value);//where for empty lines the entry.Value ll be double.NaN}

Comment: see update to answer ... I can get it to work by forcing the `EmptyPointStyle.Color` ... weird

Comment: Could you please help me with one more doubt. Now I am able to connect the points, but if the second series doesn't start from the beginning then still the line is present from the beginning-I just want the connection to be present between two non empty data points.

Comment: You shouldn't ask another question inside a comment ... create another question instead.